# SWT Form or Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am starting a project using solely SWT.
I have never used SWT so I am trying to learn the ins and outs.
I want to create a base dialog window(I will call it a dialog from working with Swing but not sure about SWT).
This window will be the first thing the user sees after clicking a menu action.  The window will eventually have buttons that perform actions, it will also have a tableviewer.  It is basically like the user opens a small application from the main application.

In Swing - I would just create a dialog class and add a tablelistener.  But with SWT, I am not sure if it is dialog or a form or what.

What should I use to create this base SWT window?

Comment: Also, take a look at JFace. This is an extra layer on top of SWT and contains classes that implement a lot of functionality, so you don't have to. For example: the TableViewer that you mentioned is part of JFace, not SWT.

Comment: I'd also look at using JFace with SWT.  JFace can run in a normal java app, and provides some model APIs on top of SWT.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of helpful dialogs in SWT. I was usually extending FormDialog, but you can take a look at the Eclipse bundles code to learn from. Please see below an example:

```
public class SomeDialog extends FormDialog {

  public SomeDialog(Shell shell) {
    super(shell);
  }

  @Override
  protected void createFormContent() {
  }
}
```

And another hint that may help you a lot. On Windows, you can open a dialog or focus a view or editor and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open the Plug-in Spy that will show you the path to the source code of that widget.